# is there a way to check if a value is zero and do this or do that in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do an sql query

```
    SELECT * from members m where abs(due/30*service_charge)>='0' 
AND abs(due/30*service_charge)<='200' group by id
```

But in some cases the value of service_charge will 0 , so i want to write it like if service_charge = 0 , then service_charge = 1;

Is there a way for this ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
select *
from members m
where abs(due/30*(case when service_charge = 0 then 1 else service_charge end) >= 0 and
      abs(due/30*(case when service_charge = 0 then 1 else service_charge end)<= 200
group by id;
```

However, this is typically handled using `NULLIF()` -- meaning that `NULL` would be returned from the calculation:

```
select *
from members m
where abs(due / 30 * nullif(service_charge, 0) >= 0 and
      abs(due / 30 * nullif(service_charge, 0) <= 200
group by id;
```

Also, don't use single quotes around numeric constants.  This confuses people and could confuse the SQL optimizer.

Comment: Could you add some dummy data to your question? Usually his answers are right on the money.

Comment: Thank you very much , the second method worked ,, nullif